# Jboss to Apache forwarding

Tags: apache, jboss, forwarding, portforwarding

> JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.1 on Linux Enterprise Redhat

I have seen several examples on how to have Apache forward requests to JBoss. I am looking to have a **JBoss server listening on port 80 forward cgi calls to an Apache server**. Can JBoss be configured to listen at port 80 and forward all requests containing "cgi-bin" to port 8080 where Apache server is listening?

The need to do this arises from

- Jboss not supporting cgi (mod_perl in my case) AFAIK
- Since i am migrating from a server where all web requests used port 80, needing to keep the port as 80 to avoid programming changes
- 99% server calls are handled by JBoss, so i want it to be the primary point of contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite JBoss handling the 99% of calls, the better architecture is to have Apache in front of JBoss.

You would have Apache serve port 80 and forward to JBoss via mod_cluster or mod_jk.  This will allow you to control your content via Apache. You *should* serve your static content directly from Apache as well.

Additionally with this architecture, you can cluster your environment and load balance across multiple servers.  This gives you higher fault tolerance (session replication, failover), handle more load, and helps you avoid server outages.

mod_cluster is recommended for EAP 6, but mod_jk works just fine too.

Comment: What we have is a single server and a few JSP/Servlet apps used by a handful of users. I would like to keep things simple. I chose JBoss over Weblogic primarily for it being simple to manage. I understand having Apache in front is the preferred architecture. Given there is no indication on JBoss being able to support CGI or it being able to forward requests to Apache, that is the only way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Right, JBoss will not support CGI. If you don't need much (just a few JSPs as you say), why not just get JBoss EWS (Apache Web + Tomcat)? EWS is quite a bit cheaper...Anyway, since JBoss is not really a web server like Apache, it really isn't designed to do that type of forwarding. I do not recommend this, but you could potentially hack together a filter that sends a redirect to the Apache server....Still, just put Apache in front and you will have much more manageable, scalable system. Everyone will be happier :)

Comment: Thanks, i am looking in to having Apache as the first point of contact and use mod_cluster. I am a little overwhelmed by the mod_cluster configuration, but will figure it out.

I am using JBoss Enterprise Application Platform. How exactly is this different from JBoss EWS?

Comment: mod_cluster is a bit confusing at first, but it is really pretty automatic...I can help you out with this if you need.  If you are using only 1 JBoss node, however, I would use mod_jk as it is lighter weight with far less overhead.  JBoss EWS is basically a supported HTTPD and Tomcat configuration, so it is again much lighter weight, because it does not have all of the JBoss services and hardening

Comment: I should note that EWS does not support clustering. So if clustering is needed, then EAP will be required

Comment: Dont expect needing clustering in our environment. I tried installing mod_cluster, but coudn't really figure out a way to make it do what i needed. I will try mod_jk next. All i need is Apache to look at all incoming requests and process it as a cgi if it contains "cgi-bin" in it. Everything else should be forwarded to port 8080 for JBoss to handle. Is mod_jk good enough for this? Thanks!

Comment: yes it is. On EAP6, add an ajp connector if you don't already have one `/subsystem=web/connector=ajp:add(name=ajp,socket-binding=ajp, protocol="AJP/1.3",scheme=http)`. generic standalone profile does not. Then add this to the web subsystem tag `instance-id=${jboss.node.name}`. This sets the jvmRoute that mod_jk needs to reference for routing. When you start the server use `-Djboss.node.name=unique-node-name`. This is the same parameter that sets the cluster node name if needed. reference [mod_jk](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OptimalModjk12Configuration) setup article for apache side config

Comment: Before i get too deep in to using technologies i fail to completely grasp, let me take and step back and lay out my need so you can tell me if i am headed in the right direction. What i need is a J2EE App Server and a perl CGI engine. What i have tried so far is to have an Apache server as the CGI engine and JBoss as the J2EE app server. Apache runs on port 8080 and JBoss runs on port 80. So far so good.

Comment: The web applications make a few (AJAX) calls to cgi programs. Here is where the browser runs in to an issue. Browser chokes on AJAX calls made to a CGI program on a different port. Which is why i am thinking both the servers (App server and CGI server) needs to be on the same port. Given all that, do you think mod_jk is the right tool for solving this problem?

Comment: I looked in to mod_jk. The documentation, including the one you referred me to, talks about adding lines to file server.xml. I cant seem to find a file name server.xml and i believe this is for Apache EWS, while i am using JBoss EAP 6.1 in a standalone mode. I will keep looking, thanks for the pointers

Comment: This chat sequence is getting too long for a stack overflow post. I started a [JBoss Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31743/jboss-help). Please join and I will talk with you there.

Comment: I ended up using mod_proxy for what i needed. I added these 2 lines to httpd.conf "ProxyRequests Off ProxyPass /AppName http://server:8080/AppName" As simple as it sounds, it does what i needed. 
@jyore - thanks much for all your help. Without your suggestions, i wouldn't have gotten here!

Comment: mod_proxy is the last I'd use...mod_jk config, follow that article...all you do in EAP is add `instance-id="${jboss.node.name}"` to the web subsystem and make sure you have the ajp connector added. If this post helped answer your questions, can you please accept it as an answer?